# Partial HOSTS file read

Tags: unix, iptables, hosts-file, tru64

I've a new entry that I put in the HOSTS file:

10.7.4.94 COMMRTU7 commrtu7 commRTU7

The first two entries ping, but the third one won't ping.
I have a list of entries like this that work fine, any ideas why this won't?

Comment: tru64 wow that brings back memories - all good apart from the slow decline into obscurity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to the answerers who gave me good information.

The problem turned out to be that there was a '^M' after the line (right after the entry in question), that didn't show when you CATed a file, but you could see in VI.
After removing the '^M' it worked as normal.

The reason it came out wrong was that I edited the HOSTS file on Windows in Notepad.
The way to do it right is to use a Unix editor, or use TextPad on Windows and Save to a UNIX file format.

Answer (score 2):

make your entry just:

```
10.7.4.94 commrtu7
```

and then try to ping all three

```
ping COMMRTU7 
ping commrtu7 
ping commRTU7
```

They are all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why it doesn't work, I am actually surprised that it appears to be case sensitive, even though RFC 952 dictates otherwise. Are you sure that the tru64 implementation is case sensitive to begin with?

Comment: While the OS is definitely case-sensitive, I'm not sure if the hostnames are, but the vendor who set this up for their software in 2000, thought it was necessary.